Подделка WebKitFormBoundary токена
Я новичок в программировании. И столкнулся с проблемой. Пытаюсь пользоваться API сайта с Chat-GPT, но никак не могу в инете найти что делать с WebKitFormBoundary. Вот код на питоне:
import requests
request=requests.post('https://ai.jaze.top/api/auth/gemini',json={
'model':'gemini-1.5-flash',
'messages': [{"role":"user","content":"привет"}]
}, headers={
'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary0BPm0koKA',
'Accept-Language':'ru,en;q=0.9',
'Content-Length':'450',
'Accept':'*/*',
'Referer':'https://ai.jaze.top/?session=2',
'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br, zstd',
'Priority':'u=1, i',
'Sec-Ch-Ua':'"Chromium";v="128", "Not;A=Brand";v="24", "YaBrowser";v="24.10",             "Yowser";v="2.5"',
'Sec-Fetch-Mode':'cors',
'Sec-Fetch-Dest':'empty',
'X-Kl-Kis-Ajax-Request':'Ajax_Request',
}
)
print(request.json())


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Для начала надо определиться что же вы отправляете, JSON или mutipart/form-data.

отправляю я json, а в заголовке указываю mutipart

@Максим если ты отправляешь JSON, то в заголовке надо указывать application/json.
